# How to rename a gnu screen session

Tags: gnu-screen

I am running a screen session and I'd like to change it's name. I know that when starting a new screen session I can use the '-S' option to give it a name. How do I change that name once the session has already started?

Answer (score 79):

There is a screen command to do this.  From the [manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html#Session-Name):

> Command: **sessionname** [***name***]
>
> (none)
>
> Rename the current session. Note that for `screen -list` the name shows up 
>      with the process-id prepended. If the argument *name* is omitted, the name 
>      of this session is displayed.
>
> ***Caution***: The `$STY` environment variable still reflects 
>      the old name. 
>      This may result in confusion. The default is constructed from the 
>      tty and host names.

To access the screen command line, use <kbd>Prefix</kbd><kbd>:</kbd>, where Prefix is typically <kbd>Ctrl-a</kbd>.

So you will most likely have to do so:
<kbd>Ctrl-a</kbd><kbd>:</kbd>`sessionname [name]`

Comment: does not work on mac. Do you mean press `control + a +:` three buttons at once?

Comment: no it means  ctrl+a (both buttons at once) followed by ':'

Answer (score 43):

To rename the window title within a screen session:

- press and release <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> and then press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>

To rename the actual session name (displayed with `screen -ls`) use:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> `:sessionname newName`. <sub>More details at https://superuser.com/a/370553/65975.</sub>

Comment: It seems this changes the window title but not the name shown in, for example, `screen -R` or `screen -list`.

Comment: As @reg states, this changes the title of the current window as seen in `Ctrl-a "` - not the screen session as a whole, which was the question asked by the OP.

Comment: does not work on mac. Do you mean press `control + shift +a`?

Comment: @kww it's press `Ctrl-a` first, then `Shift-a`.

Comment: `C+a` doesn't help at all, but the link you posted did

Comment: 'cause that's `Ctrl` but not `C`

Answer (score 14):

```
# screen -S old_session_name -X sessionname new_session_name
```

Comment: This didn't work for me on Fedora 29 (Screen version 4.06.02 (GNU) 23-Oct-17), I had to use `Ctrl a` followed by `:sessionname <new-session-name>`. It did, however, work on OS X with Screen version 4.00.03 (FAU) 23-Oct-06

Answer (score 2):

Don't forget to update the contents of the `$STY` variable with the new name:

`$ session -S OldName -X sessionname NewName`

`$ echo $STY`

```
PID.OldName  <- Where PID is the actual Process ID on your system
```

Note:  If you tried a `screen top` at this point, it'll fail with a message about not being able to find the old session in `/run/uscreens/S-username`.

`$ export STY=PID.NewName`  <- Where PID is the actual Process ID on your system

`$ screen top`

This will now work, since the `$STY` variable is being used (along with other purposes) to find the location in `/run/uscreens/S-username` of the session file.

Answer (score 0):

May not be answering this exact question, but to change the name displayed at the bottom like `(0 bash)`, you can use

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>a</kbd> then `:title <newtitle>` to change the `bash` part
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>a</kbd> then `:number <newnumber>` to change the number (which will also change relative order of your session instances).